# help me in writing test class

Tags: unit-test

```
 public List<SelectOption> getPickListValues (string field_name){
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();               
    Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = case.getSObjectType();                 
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe(); 
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> field_map = sobject_describe.fields.getMap();                 
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = field_map.get(field_name).getDescribe().getPickListValues();                 
    for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) {  
        options.add(new SelectOption(a.getLabel(), a.getValue()));                                
    }
    return options; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is accessing the picklist values that are part of the SObject's metadata so no SObject data rows are involved.

A basic test that ensures the code doesn't generate an exception and does return values is:

```
@isTest
private class TestClass {
    @isTest picklistValues() {
        ClassBeingTested c = new ClassBeingTested();
        List<SelectOption> options = c.getPickListValues('Priority');
        System.assertNotEquals(0, options.size());
        for (SelectOption option : options) {
            System.assertNotEquals(null, option.getLabel());
            System.assertNotEquals(null, option.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

You could add further asserts to check the `SelectOption` label and value values.

Note that you could make the code more re-usable by passing in the type and field and making it a static method in a class:

```
public static List<SelectOption> getSelectOptions(SObjectType t, SObjectField f) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@isTest(SeeAllData='true')

 private class TestClassName {

    static testMethod void validateClass () {

    ObjectName__c upd=[select Id, picklistField1__c, picklistField2__c, from ObjectName__c Limit 1];  // in case you are updating a record

        upd.picklistField1__c='picklist_value';
        upd.picklistField2__c='picklist_value';


        update upd;

         ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(upd);
        ClassName cn = new ClassName(sc);

        PageReference pageRef = Page.visualforcePage_Name;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(upd.Id));
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);


        cn.classMethod(); //

        cn.save(); // for 'Save' action on visualforce page
 }
}
```

Comment: When writing unit tests you should try and avoid using SeeAllData. Try instantiating some of the types and objects that your test class needs access too.

Comment: Agrred, SeeAllData should be avoided, instead you can create test data in the class itself. Something like below:                                                                   List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();

        for(Integer i=0;i<numAccts;i++) {

            Account a = new Account(Name='TestAccount' + i);

            accts.add(a);

        }

        insert accts;